# Form : sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice, choose the method

Tags: forms, symfony1, doctrine, widget

In my form I want to use a widget Doctrine, but I can't change the method use to display the result of the doctrine query.

I have make a function in my model :

```
public function quartiers() {
  return $this->getQuartier();
}
```

And in MyClassForm :

```
$this->widgetSchema['list_quartiers'] = new sfWidgetFormDoctrineChoice(array('model'=>Parclogement',
'add_empty'=>false, 'method' => 'quartiers()', 'query'=> $result = Doctrine_Query::create()->select('p.quartier'->from('Parclogement p'->groupBy('quartier')));
```

I have this error :

```
Unknown method Parclogement::quartiers()
```

When I try my widget with the default method (__toString), It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's the parentheses after 'quartiers()'? Try making it 'method' => 'quartiers'?